# Manually ordering table rows jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, menu, row

I am having interface of table row as menu tabs. I have to give interface for manually ordering table rows by jQuery plugin so that I can save tabs order and display according to. Please suggest me jQuery plugin for manually ordering table rows.

Update:
With these features also one feature required:
By clicking on column name ordering column names.

Comment: Do you mean drag and drop of table rows ?

Comment: dataTables is pretty good - http://datatables.net/

Comment: I require [TableDnD](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) feature with [jqGrid](http://demo.techbrij.com/523/column%20reorder%20jqgrid%20demo.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-drag-drop/) out, it uses lists instead of table, but I think you can customize it to table or use it as it is.

When you change the order, it stores the order in the database by ajax request. If you found that useful, download the code [here](http://papermashup.com/drag-drop-with-php-jquery/)

OR if you want to do it strictly using tables, Check [this](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) out.

### Drag and drop between columns

you can use [jqGrid](http://demo.techbrij.com/523/column%20reorder%20jqgrid%20demo.php) OR may be [drag and drop plugin](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?showDownload=true&whichScript=drag_drop_nodes) by dhtmlgoodies, but it uses list instead of table

Good luck, hope it helps.

Comment: It is very good plugin. Is there any plugin having same functionality with ordering by clicking on column name.

Comment: TableDnD plugin satisfies. It is my main requirement. But it would be good if plugin also have features like jqGrid

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Glad that you got it solved. To make TableDnD work as you wanted, you have to play around its JS and customize them. TableDnD is the best for customizing as it comes with a very detailed documentation. Accept my answer if you found it useful. Thanks :)